# Is this function an injection from A to B?

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

We are given the sets,

$A = (0, 1], B = [1, ∞) \in \Bbb R$

I'm trying to find two injective functions to show that it the sets are bijective.

The first one I found I am convinced but a figured a more trained eye can maybe confirm this,

For $f:A \to B$ I found $\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2\sqrt(arcsin(x))}$

Can the inverse of this function be used to show a bijection?

Comment: Slightly simpler: $f(x) = 1/x$.

Comment: @MartinR "slightly"

Comment: Sets cannot be bijective. What you probably mean is that $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality.

Comment: @MartinR Eh, it's actually a pretty common thing to say nowadays. Everyone knows what someone means when they say $A$ and $B$ are bijective.

Comment: @DonThousand: OK, I never heard it before.

Comment: @MartinR $\textit{technically}$, whenever you say that a function is bijective, since the function is a set, you are saying that a set is bijective. but i agree with you here that they should have said something along the lines of “$A$ and $B$ are in bijection” instead of “$A$ and $B$ are bijective”.

Comment: Am I right to say the function f(x)=1/x is a bijective function for the given sets A and B?